# How to make the table cell visibility hidden in itextsharp pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have a table with fixed cells of 2. I want to make the visibility of table cell hidden as per my condition. My condition is

```
PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(2);
table1.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 200f, 100f});
table1.TotalWidth = 800f;//table size

foreach (GridViewRow row in grdtimetable.Rows)
{
    Label lblday = (Label)row.FindControl("lbltopicvalue");
    Label lblperiod1 = (Label)row.FindControl("lblperiod1");

    table1.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    table1.AddCell(new Phrase("Days", time550));

    if(lblperiod1 .Text!="NULL"||lblperiod1 .Text!="")
    {
        table1.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        table1.AddCell(new Phrase(""+lblperiod1 .text+"", time550));
    }
    else
    {
        //Here I want to make this cell visibility hidden
    }
```

}

Is it possible? If it is, kindly help me

Comment: How do you define *hidden*? Is it sufficient to add an empty cell without any border?

Comment: @rhens,I didint get what you meant actually, My requirement is,Actually I am trying to generate a time table.I have set column number as 5. But some certain situation the the period numbers will be 2 then the other 3 cell should be hidden..

Comment: waiting for @Bruno Lowegi..

Comment: Suppose you want to hide cells 2 and 3, which one of [these results](http://i.imgur.com/A3EgqMz.png) is what you want?  If none of them, please clarify your question.

Comment: @rhens,Option 2 or 3. Onemore condition is there. If 2 is empty the remains also will empty(3,4 and 5)

Comment: @rhens, see my updated question

Comment: It's simply a matter of adding empty `PdfPCell`s and/or counting the number of empty cells. I'll post code for the 3 options as an answer.

Comment: @ rhens, Is it shows the empty cells? I dont wanna see this empty cells

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. I'll illustrate a few.

If you want to keep the positions of the other table cells the same, i.e. not shift them to the left, you can simple add empty cells:

```
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Option 1:"));
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
table.SpacingBefore = 10;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    if (i == 2 || i == 3)
    {
        // Add an empty cell
        PdfPCell empty = new PdfPCell();
        empty.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
        table.AddCell(empty);
    }
    else
    {
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell " + i)));
    }
}
doc.Add(table);
```

If you do want to shift cells to the left, but preserve column width, you can add empty cells at the end of the row. This is useful if you want have the same table layout for multiple tables with a different number of empty cells.

(You can get the same result by adjusting the table width, instead of adding empty cells, but it would involve more calculations.)

```
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Option 2:"));
PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(5);
table2.SpacingBefore = 10;
int emptycells = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    if (i == 2 || i == 3)
    {
        // Count the number of empty cells
        emptycells++;
    }
    else
    {
        table2.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell " + i)));
    }
}
// Add all empty cells at the end
for (int i = 0; i < emptycells; i++)
{
    PdfPCell empty2 = new PdfPCell();
    empty2.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
    table2.AddCell(empty2);
}
doc.Add(table2);
```

Finally, if you simply determine how many empty cells there will be, before creating the table, you can adjust the number of columns in the table.

(Again, you can adjust the table width, to get a result similar to the previous option.)

```
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Option 3:"));
// Determine the number of empty cells before hand
int emptycellsCounted = 2;
PdfPTable table3 = new PdfPTable(5 - emptycellsCounted);
table3.SpacingBefore = 10;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    if (i == 2 || i == 3)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        table3.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell " + i)));
    }
}
doc.Add(table3);

doc.Close();
```

You say there's an additional constraint: if a cell is empty, all following cells will also be empty. In that case, options 1 and 2 are the same.

The result of the 3 code samples:

[image: Hidden cells]